Using external code with chrome extenstion v3
I want to inject my remote script to chrome extenstion, but I think manifest V3 don't let me do that. How to overcome that barrier?.
Here are the option I have tried.
const dynamicScript = fetch(...);
const data = {}   // to pass into dynamic script

chrome.scripting.executeScript(
   {
      target: { tabId: details.tabId },
      world: "MAIN",     // most important part
      func: data => {
         (new Function('data', dynamicScript))(data);
      },
      args: [data]  // passing app into func above
   }
); 

Thank you for your help

If Chrome doesn't let you do it, then don't. Even if you could bypass the automated detection, you wouldn't be able to pass the code review. See Deal with remote hosted code violations.

I don't plan to make the extension public I just use it locally
